# JsonSlurper avoid trimming last zero in a string

Tags: groovy, jsonslurper

I am using JsonSlurper in groovy to convert a json text to a map.

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper();
def parsedInput = slurper.parseText("{amount=10.00}");
```

Result is

```
[amount:10.0]
```

I need result without trimming last zero. Like

```
[amount:10.00]
```

Have checked various solutions but this is not getting converted without trimming last zero. Am I missing something here.

One of the ways I have found is to give input as:

```
{amount="10.00"}
```

Answer (score 3):

In numbers and maths, `10.00` ***IS*** `10.0`

They are exactly the same number.

They just have different String representations.

If you need to display `10.0` to the user as `10.00` then that is a conversion thing, as you will need to convert it to a String with 2 decimal places

Something like:

```
def stringRepresentation = String.format("%.02f", 10.0)
```

But for any calculations, `10.0` and `10.00` are the same thing

---

### Edit -- Try again...

Right so when you have the json:

```
{"amount"=10.00}
```

The value on the right is a floating point number.

To keep the extra zero (which is normally dropped by every sane representation of numbers), you will need to convert it to a String.

To do this, you can use the `String.format` above (other methods are available).

You cannot keep it as a floating point number with an extra zero.

Numbers don't work like that in every language I can think of...  They might do in COBOL from the back of my memory, but that's way off track

Comment: that is not his question, his question is about showing it correctly (keep 2 digits behind the comma)

Comment: No it isn't, it's a misunderstanding of number representations vs string representations

Comment: Your initial answer was purely about number representation/math which he did not ask, however your edit answers his question which is related to string representation :) up voted

Comment: i understand mathematically 10.00 and 10.0 are same. But i have a requirement where i need to preserve the zero

Answer (score 0):

The issue ([GROOVY-6922](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6922)) was fixed in Groovy version 2.4.6.  With 2.4.6 the scale of the number should be retained.